# HttpClient post with parameters in body

Tags: c#, postman, dotnet-httpclient

I am successful using Postman doing a post for authentication. However, I can't seem to get it to work from C# and am getting a 401 error. The password and username are verified the same as in Postman.  How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```cs
var url = AppConstants.ApiLoginUrl;
var uriRequest = new Uri(url);
string httpResponseBody;

using (var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var content = new HttpStringContent(string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", email, password), Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try
    {
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(uriRequest, content);
        ...
    }
}
```

Here are the settings in Postman for header and body.

[image]

[image]

Now using this code for the content parameter:

```cs
var content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", email),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
});
```

Upon a closer look, it appears the username is encoded in Fiddler for both the Postman and code requests. So, my theory about using an encoded username is not quite right.  Here at the snapshots of the requests from Fiddler... Is is possible?

Postman headers:

[image: Postman headers]

Code headers:

[image: Code headers]

Raw View Postman * showing encoded username field:

[image: Raw view revised]

Raw view code:

[image: Raw code]

Comment: Did you run fiddler to actually see what is getting sent?

Comment: Try it with a `User-Agent` header.

Comment: @OldProgrammer yes, I did, and discovered the username is being encoded. So, russ@domain.com is going across the wire as russ%40domain.com and I need to set it to not encode somehow.

Comment: User-Agent is not the issue @crowcoder

Comment: Because you tried it, or something else worked, or you don't believe it? Some services check for user-agent even if it is a custom value.

Comment: Yup, I tried it, I am can use custom useragent value for the service from Postman with success, and failure with the same user agent from the code. I can also omit the user agent from Postman and it works as well, however I noticed there is a Postman User Agent instead that I see in Fiddler. I think the crux of my problem is that the username is encoded and I don't want that.

Comment: On postman screens you have `/authentificate` and on the others for code `/authentication`. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: @khoroshevj Awesome pickup! Yes, that was indeed it. Thanks for your help everyone! Glad I put those screen shots up for a second pair of eyes to look at! This was the last piece to this puzzle on this post and I should be all set now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that for [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) applications Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient() is the recommended way to do this, plus make sure your URL's do not have typos. :)

```
var url = AppConstants.ApiLoginUrl;
var uriRequest = new Uri(url);

var content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", email),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
});

using (var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(uriRequest, content);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your content to the following

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", email),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
});
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, the username is being encoded however. So, a username of user@domain.com is going across the wire as user%40domain.com and I need to set it to not encode somehow, because the server is validating user@domain.com and failing on user%40domain.com ...

Answer (score 1):

I am using this function to send [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) requests with parameters. Where `Dictionary<string, string> data` is the key/value as expected by the web service.

```
public static T PostCast<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data)).Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient for a UWP app, so the methods are slightly different the System version you have above. For example, HttpFormUrlEncodedContent instead of FormUrlEncodedContent. So bottom line is  am having a difficult time modifying the content after it is encoded to replace the encoded "%40" with "@". Can't seem to find the equivalent of a HttpFormUrlContent method (without the encode). I need the username going over the wire as is. Ideas?

Comment: @user3810967
Isn't it an option to use System version ?
as `System.Net.Http` seems more general and more widely used

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by remove the trailing "/" from the URL the HttpClient was posting to.